# bumblebeed: No integrated video card found, quitting

Tags: drivers, graphics, intel-graphics, nvidia-optimus, bumblebee

I'm trying to get Bumblebee working on Ubuntu 14.10 x64 and NVIDIA OPTIMUS:

- Intel HD3000 (don't know which drivers are used: I've installed Intel(R) Graphics Installer for Linux* 1.0.7 while being on 14.04 and then upgraded to 14.10)

 - NVIDIA GT555M with 331.113 driver

```
~$ lspci | grep VGA
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 2nd Generation Core Processor Family Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 09)
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GF106M [GeForce GT 555M] (rev a1)
```

```
~$ optirun --status
[  793.908226] [ERROR]The Bumblebee daemon has not been started yet or the socket path /var/run/bumblebee.socket was incorrect.
[  793.908349] [ERROR]Could not connect to bumblebee daemon - is it running?
```

```
~$ bumblebeed
[  842.118430] [ERROR]No integrated video card found, quitting.
```

^ How can I fix that?

Comment: Did you fix that somehow?

Comment: @displayname nope